# div background color not coming when print preview occurs on the page

Tags: html, css

I have one div in my page:

```
<div id="div1>

welcome
</div>
```

I need to set background color for this div using css. so i used background-color css in our page, it works as expected but when I try to print it, it is not showing respective color.

So, I tried to use media code. It works in chrome browser but I don't know whether it will work in all browsers.

```
@media print {
        #div1 {
            background-color: #E42314 !important;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 

        }
    }
    #div1 {
        background-color: #E42314 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this option in browser's print settings where you need to flip the "*show background colors and images*".

Because this is a browser setting, you won't be able to set this through code.

For example if you are using Chrome, the print options will look like this:

[image]

For IE, it will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: what about other browsers ?

Comment: @SivaRajini: There. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the  `!important` attribute onto the the background-color tag in order for it to show up, you do not need the web-kit tag or even need it wrapped in the @print.

`background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;`

Comment: I can get it to work on divs, but for table rows I cannot. Are you trying it on a div or different element?

Comment: I was trying on a table row. So it seems that it does not work on `<tr>` as it failed for you and I, at least in Chromium

Comment: Correct, if you can figure it out on `<tr>` then please let me know!

Comment: Jeeez! it works! I just created a quick html list from a sql database using shell, js, handlebars just to make it prettier and print a single copy! such an endeavor to make it work! CSS standard is a MESS! someday it should be completely redone!
Thx Flea!